# Margins got set to every webform and every <div> automatically. How to correct it?

Tags: html, css, asp.net, webforms

I am creating a website for which I used a template. I was working on different webforms and all of a sudden margins got set to every webform, every `<div>` of every webform.

Even if I add new webform and paste the HTML code of that template, then too margins automatically get applied to it.

How to correct this?
///////////////////////////Home Page/////////////////////////////////////

```
 <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Home.aspx.cs" Inherits="Home" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>TMPH00043</title>
<link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
<div class="menu-wrapper">
  <div class="menu">
      <ul>
          <li><a href="Home.aspx" class="active">HOME</a></li>
          <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
          <li><a href="services.html">GALLERY</a></li>
          <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
          <li><a href="contact.html">LOGIN</a></li>
      </ul>
      <p>
          &nbsp;</p>
  </div>

&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Height="140px" ImageUrl="~/images/Infinity K_Power Of Words_ZkFrRQ.jpg" Width="178px" />

</div>
<!--- menu-wrapper div end -->
<div class="clearing"></div>
<div class="banner-wrapper">
  <div class="bannerlef"><img src="images/banner-wrap-left.jpg" /></div>
  <div class="banner-container">
    <div class="banner">
      <div class="banner-content">
        <h1>SMS</h1>
        <h2>Student Management System</h2>
        <a href="Login.aspx">Login</a> </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!--- banner wrapper div end -->
<div class="footer-wrapper">
  <div class="footer">
    <p> © 2012 All Rights Reserved.<a href="http://www.alltemplates.com"> < www.alltemplateneeds.com ></a> Images From: <a href="http://photorack.net">www.photorack.net</a> </p>
  </div>
</div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

////////////////////////////////Login Page/////////////////////////////////////

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Login.aspx.cs" Inherits="Login" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title></title>
<link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

</head>
<body>
<div class="menu-wrapper">
  <div class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="Home.aspx">home</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.html">about</a></li>
      <li><a href="services.html">gallery</a></li>
      <li><a href="works.html">contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="Login.aspx" class="active" >login</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="call">
    <h1>Call us :<span> ( 000 ) 8888 888888</span></h1>
  </div>
</div>
<!--- menu-wrapper div end -->
<div class="clearing"></div>
<div class="border-bottom"></div>
<div class="logo-wrapper">
  <div class="leftshadow"><img src="images/logo-wrap-left.jpg" /></div>
  <div class="logo">
    <h1>student management system</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="rightshadow"><img src="images/logo-wrap-right.jpg" /></div>
</div>
<div class="clearing"></div>
<!--- banner wrapper div end -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="panel-wrapper">
      <div class="mid-panel-content">
        <div class="title">
          <h1 style="color: #9E6B8D">Enter your username and password :</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="border"></div>
          <form id="form1" runat="server">
          <div class=" margin-top marLeft10">
            <label> 
              <br />
                <span style="color: #838D9D">
                  User Name&nbsp;
                </span>
                <asp:TextBox ID="textUN" runat="server" Width="328px"></asp:TextBox>
                <br />
            </label>
            <br/>
            <label>
               <span style="color: #838D9D">
                  Password
               </span>&nbsp;&nbsp;
               <asp:TextBox ID="textPassword" runat="server" Width="328px" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
               <br />
             </label>
             <br/>
          <div>
              <span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

                 <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" runat="server" Text="Admin" OnCheckedChanged="RadioButton1_CheckedChanged" ForeColor="#838D9D" />

              </span>
               <label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                  <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton2" runat="server" Text="Student" ForeColor="#838D9D"/>
               </label>
              &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br />
                   &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br />
              &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
              <asp:Button ID="submit" runat="server" value="SUBMIT" ForeColor="#75577A" style="text-align: center; border:0px;" Text="SUBMIT" BackColor="#2C3847" Font-Size="Large" Height="45px" Width="77px" OnClick="submit_Click"/>

            </div>
          </div>
          </form>
        <div class="clearing"></div>
        <div class="address">
          <div class="panel">
            <div class="title">
              <h1>Address - 01</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="content">
              <p>DUCAT, Sector-16,<br />
                  Faridabad, Haryana, India</p>
              <p><span>Phone :</span> 000 888 88888</p>
              <p><span>Email :</span> <a href="mailto:info@companyname.com">info@SMS.com</a></p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="panel">
            <div class="title">
              <h1>Address - 02</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="content">
              <p>DUCAT,<br />
                  Def. Col. , New Delhi, India</p>
              <p><span>Phone :</span> 000 888 88888</p>
              <p><span>Email :</span> <a href="mailto:info@companyname.com">info@SMS.com</a></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearing"></div>
  <!--- panel wrapper div end -->
</div>
<!--- container div end -->
<div class="clearing"></div>
<div class="footer-wrapper">
  <div class="footer">
    <p> © 2012 All Rights Reserved.<a href="http://www.alltemplates.com"> < www.alltemplateneeds.com ></a> Images From: <a href="http://photorack.net">www.photorack.net</a> </p>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you share code ? want to see what you have tried

Comment: There are many pages ...and a lot of HTML code in every page. Should i still share??

Comment: I guess you r using master page and whatever the new page you create will inherit that, if so share the master page code and screen shot will work as if now

Comment: "I" is always capital on English.

Comment: I haven't used master page.